# Solve an implicit equation Python

Tags: python, equation

I want to write a code to solve for "y" with relative error %1 in equation below:

[image]

In the equation we have the values of "`b=2,  x=1,  n=0.015,  S_0=0.002,  Q=21`" and y should be calculated.

I write this code:

```
b=float(input('b='))
x=float(input('x= '))
n=float(input('n= '))
s=float(input('S_0= '))
Q=float(input('Q= '))
Q=(1/n)*((y*(b+x*y))**(5/3))/((b+2*y*(1+x**2)**(1/2))**(2/3)))*s
print(y)
```

It doesn't work.

I am not familiar how to solve the implicit equation in python. if it wasn't implicit I could write the equation with respect to y then write inputs. but here I don't know what I should do.

Comment: Welcome to SO, what would you do if you had to solve it by hand using numerical method to approximate it? Are you aware of Newton method?

Comment: @jlandercy, Thank you. I am not aware of Newton method.

Comment: The answer of @flabons below makes use of it as implemented in [`scipy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can rephrase your equation by defining like below f(y) and then find the root of it with fsolve

```py
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
def f(y,b=2,x=1,n=0.015,S_0=0.002,Q=21):
    return (1/n)*((y*(b+x*y))**(5/3))/((b+2*y*(1+x**2)**(1/2))**(2/3))*S_0-Q
a=fsolve(f,1)
print(a)
print(f(a))
```

Comment: That would be great if you parametrize `f` and pass parameters to it using `args` switch instead of using global variables.

Comment: Thank you, I write the code but it gives output : [7.64530883]  [-3.55271368e-14] but answer for y should be 1.846

Comment: I followed the suggestions by @jlandercy and added the paramters to the function. And with the given paramters the solution should be indeed y0 approx7.64. Which you see if you plot the function.  For some function you may get different solutions depending on the starting value of your of fsolve, but that is only for functions with several local minima which you do not have in this case.

Comment: The equation as stated by the OP has [three roots](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28y*%282%2B1*y%29%29%5E%285%2F3%29%2F%28%282%2B2*y*sqrt%281%2B1**2%29%29%5E%282%2F3%29%29*0.002%2F0.015+%3D+21), two conjugates complex and one real which is about 7.64 as you found.

Comment: The problem of your paramaterization is that you cannot use it with fsolve. It should be args instead of kwargs: signature is `equation(y, x, b, S0, n, Q0)` and call to fsolve is then `fsolve(equation, 0.1, args=(1, 2, 0.002, 0.015, 21))` Then you can solve multiple system without rewriting any code just passing the right tuple of parameters. Cheers

Comment: @jlandercy , Yes I get 7.64 with calculator too. but it is strange because on the paper it said answer is 1.846 !

Comment: @dgf Any typo or bad setup? We confirmed that root in three different ways.

Comment: @jlandercy Yes, maybe there is a typo. anyway it works!

Comment: @jlandercy the values are just defaults and you can call fslove with a tuple of parameters anyhow.