# Outputting results of loop of a loop

Tags: python, for-loop, numerical-methods, scipy-optimize, equation-solving

I am iteratively solving this implicit equation

[image: (here)]

using `fsolve` within a `for` loop over a range of values of the independent variable, `V`.

I also want to vary `I_L` and run the `for` loop over each value and generate an individual text files.

I know how to use the open and write text files, what I'm struggling with is setting loops up correctly to output what I want.

I have coded a simpler example below to allow for ease of understanding since it's just the loops I'm stuck on.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import scipy.constants as sc

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 1001)

C_vary = [0, 1, 2, 3]

def equation(y, x, C):
    return C - np.exp(x+y) - y

for C in C_vary:
    
    y = []
    
   Solve equation at each value of C_vary and output y values to new list of
   results
```

Comment: This is confusing; what is the "y" argument entering your equation(y,x,C)?

Comment: The original equation is y = C - exp(x+y). Writing it in the function 'equation' like this means that it is assumed C - exp(x+y) - y = 0, which it does. Please see the answer to another user's question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64400639/solve-an-implicit-equation-python. My definition of 'equation' should make sense once you've read. I use the same method as used there to solve the equation. Just confused about the looping to get out individual text files for each C_vary

Comment: The change of notation makes the question hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

I have introduced an initial guess for the function y(x), but you  can check the details further. The output y is a list, with each element corresponding to a value of the C_vary parameters, for each x.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import scipy.constants as sc

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 1001)
C_vary = [0, 1, 2, 3]

def equation(y, x, C):
    return C - np.exp(x+y) - y

y0 = np.exp( 0.5*x ) #initial guess 
y  = [ fsolve( equation, y0, (x,ci) ) for ci in C_vary ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are after `I` as a function of `V` and other parameters, you can solve the equation by means of the Lambert `W` function.

It has the form

```
z = e^(a z + b)
```

where `z` is linear in `I`, and this is

```
- a z e^(- a z) = - a e^b
```

or

```
z = - W(-a e^b) / a.
```