# Solving implicit equation with scipy.optimize.fsolve

Tags: python, scipy, fsolve

I came to ask this question from [the very similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64400639/solve-an-implicit-equation-python) where I "learned" how to employ fsolve to solve for solving implicit equations.
My equation is defined by this function:

```
def fn4(Fs):
    return ( np.sum( (lamL * c + lamW * np.tan(np.radians(phi))) 
                 / (np.cos(lamA) * (1 + np.tan(lamA) * np.tan(np.radians(phi)) / Fs))
               ) / np.sum(lamW * np.sin(lamA))
           )
```

where:

```
c = 10
phi = 30
lamela1 = {'W':887.36, 'alpha':np.radians(46.71), 'L':19.325}
lamela2 = {'W':1624.8, 'alpha':np.radians(22.054), 'L':14.297}
lamela3 = {'W':737.43, 'alpha':np.radians(1.9096), 'L':13.258}
lamele = [lamela1, lamela2, lamela3]

lamW = np.array([[i['W'] for i in lamele]])
lamA = np.array([[i['alpha'] for i in lamele]])
lamL = np.array([[i['L'] for i in lamele]])
```

Now, I solved this by making a simple recursion:

```
def iterf(f, Fsi):
    if np.isclose(Fsi, fn4(Fsi)) == True:
        return Fsi
    else:
        return iterf(f, fn4(Fsi))
```

which gives

```
iterf(fn4, 1)
1.8430
```

But when I try to use `scipy.optimize.fsolve` (as `fsolve(fn4, 1)`), then i get:

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  / (np.cos(lamA) * (1 + np.tan(lamA) * np.tan(np.radians(phi)) / Fs))
```

I don't know how exactly does `fsolve` work (which I'd like to learn), but my guess is that for the optimization it needs to input Fs as 0 at one point, which produces the zero-division. How can I use a function like this one to get the output?

EDIT:
The theoretical background is stability of soil slopes. The Fs, which is the result, is the factor of safety - a measure whose values is >1 for stable slopes, and <=1 for unstable slopes. The chosen method is really simple as it requires the solution of only this one equation. The slope is discretized with a number of "lamellae" or "columns", in this case only 3 for simplicity.

Comment: It sounds like this didn't start as a root finding exercise. Can you show the theoretical definition for your original equation?

Comment: How is iterf called?

Comment: I updated my question to answer yours.

Comment: Looking at the limit of the function as it approaches zero, it appears the function approaches 0 as x approaches 0. There are multiple different solutions, but they depend on whether you consider 0 to be a root you're interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to solve `fn4(x) == x`, that is, find a *fixed point* of `fn4`. (If not, please clarify what the recursion is for.) However, the first argument of `fsolve` is supposed to be the function for which you want a *root*, so you're actually calling `fsolve` to solve `fn4(x) == 0`.

Recommendations:

- `fsolve` is a [legacy function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#legacy-functions); prefer [`root`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html)
- `root` is generalized for multivariable problems, but you have a scalar function, so prefer [`root_scalar`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root_scalar.html).
- Use `root_scalar` to solve for the fixed point as follows.

```py
import numpy as np

# OP's code
c = 10
phi = 30
lamela1 = {'W':887.36, 'alpha':np.radians(46.71), 'L':19.325}
lamela2 = {'W':1624.8, 'alpha':np.radians(22.054), 'L':14.297}
lamela3 = {'W':737.43, 'alpha':np.radians(1.9096), 'L':13.258}
lamele = [lamela1, lamela2, lamela3]

lamW = np.array([[i['W'] for i in lamele]])
lamA = np.array([[i['alpha'] for i in lamele]])
lamL = np.array([[i['L'] for i in lamele]])

def fn4(Fs):
    return ( np.sum( (lamL * c + lamW * np.tan(np.radians(phi)))
                 / (np.cos(lamA) * (1 + np.tan(lamA) * np.tan(np.radians(phi)) / Fs))
               ) / np.sum(lamW * np.sin(lamA))
           )

# Solution code
from scipy.optimize import fsolve, root, root_scalar
# The `lambda` function returns zero when `fn4(x) == x`
res = root_scalar(lambda x: fn4(x) - x, x0=1)
# or, if you want to restrict the search within a bracket
# res = root_scalar(lambda x: fn4(x) - x, bracket=(0.1, 3))
np.testing.assert_allclose(res.root, fn4(res.root))
```